# How to identify CPU(s) on Linux EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, central-processing-unit, amazon-ami, xeon, vcpu

I'm running a Linux c5d.9xlarge instance and wondering what CPU it's using. [Amazon's Instance Types webpage](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) states:

> C5 and C5d 12xlarge, 24xlarge, and metal instances have the following
>   specs:
>
> - Custom 2nd generation Intel Xeon Scalable Processors (Cascade Lake)
>     with a sustained all core Turbo frequency of 3.6GHz and single core
>     turbo frequency of up to 3.9GHz.
>
> All other C5 and C5d instances have the following specs:
>
> - Custom 2nd generation Intel Xeon Scalable Processors (Cascade Lake)
>     with a sustained all core Turbo frequency of 3.6GHz and single core
>     turbo frequency of up to 3.9GHz or 1st generation Intel Xeon Platinum
>     8000 series (Skylake-SP) processor with a sustained all core Turbo
>     frequency of up to 3.4GHz, and single core turbo frequency of up to
>     3.5 GHz.

So I'm curious whether I have a 1st generation Xeon Platinum 8000 series or a 2nd generation Xeon Scalable Processor. How can I check? `uname -a` just gives me:

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux ip-111-11-11-111.us-west-1.compute.internal 4.14.165-131.185.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 15 14:19:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm using the `amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20200207.1-x86_64-gp2` AMI.

Comment: `lscpu` or `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @MarkWagner exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. Please post as answer so I can give credit. Looks like I'm using the 1st generation `Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8124M CPU @ 3.00GHz` :(. At least it shows "CPU MHz: 3400.023", so it's able to go full turbo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lscpu` or `cat /proc/cpuinfo` should have what you need.